# Repetir valor en consulta SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta sql:

```
select empresa, fecha, tipodocto, correlativo, linea, producto, CantidadAsignada,  
case
when linea = 1 then 'PRODUCTO'
else 'RECURSO'
end 
as tipolinea, (select producto where linea = 1) as colAux
from DocumentoD where empresa = 'E01' and tipodocto = 'ORDEN DE PRODUCCION' and year(fecha) > 
2020 order by Correlativo, Linea
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr y no he podido, es que en la *colAux* se repita el primer valor, por ejemplo en el correlativo 31937 todos los valores de *colAux* debe ser 'ZZZ007011', en el correlativo 31944 sea ZZZ006001 y así sucesivamente.

Comment: En el `(select producto where linea = 1) as colAux` está limitando a que solo se muestre en aquellos registros donde su columna Linea sea igual 1.

Comment: Yo insertaría la combinación `correlativo-producto` donde `item=1` en una tabla temporal. Luego haría un `join` sobre el correlativo y hago `select temp.producto as colAux` en la última columna.

Comment: vas a tener que poner un switch/case para  cada correlativo que quieras que derive un valor en  col aux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba y me comentas:

```sql
with subquery as (
select empresa, fecha, tipodocto, correlativo, linea, producto, CantidadAsignada,  
case
when linea = 1 then 'PRODUCTO'
else 'RECURSO'
end 
as tipolinea, (select producto where linea = 1) as colAux
from DocumentoD where empresa = 'E01' and tipodocto = 'ORDEN DE PRODUCCION' and year(fecha) > 
2020 order by Correlativo, Linea
)

select s1.empresa, s1.fecha, s1.tipodocto, s1.correlativo, s1.linea, s1.producto, s1.CantidadAsignada, s1.tipolinea, s2.colAux
from subquery s1 join subquery s2 on s1.correlativo = s2.correlativo
where not s2.colAux is null
```

Lo que hace este script es hacer uso de CTE; luego se hace uso de JOIN para cruzar los registros y especificamos que la condición sea el correlativo. Como ya dije, traerán registros cruzados lo que derivará en nulos, eso lo especificamos en la cláusula WHERE. Eso sería todo.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de seguir adelante con la otra respuesta, sería mejor que intentes algo mucho más sencillo. Solo necesitas la función FIRST_VALUE() y con eso no necesitas repetir nada del código.

En el ejemplo, además corrijo el formato para hacerlo mucho más legible y la condición para mostrar una forma de hacerlo que permita utilizar índices en caso de que existan.

```
SELECT  empresa, 
        fecha, 
        tipodocto, 
        correlativo, 
        linea, 
        producto, 
        CantidadAsignada,  
        CASE WHEN linea = 1 
                THEN 'PRODUCTO' 
            ELSE 'RECURSO' END  AS tipolinea, 
        FIRST_VALUE( producto) OVER( PARTITION BY correlativo ORDER BY linea) AS colAux
FROM  DocumentoD 
WHERE empresa   =  'E01' 
AND   tipodocto =  'ORDEN DE PRODUCCION' 
AND   fecha     >= '20210101'
ORDER BY Correlativo, 
         Linea;
```